# RunApp: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/ChainResolver

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.2.0.RELEASE, Grails 2.2.2 and Groovy Compiler 2.0.

When I try to run an app I get the following error:
Error executing script RunApp: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/ChainResolver

Can anyone help me?

Best regards.

Comment: are you using ivy? If yes, do you have ivy dependencies in your BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: Hi rimero,
I think I found the cause of this issue.
 Message: Error mapping onto view [/index]: Error evaluating expression [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()] on line [90]: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
So, deleting line 90, it works. It seems the method to get Groovy version is missing.
I don't know if i'm using ivy. I'll try to find it. It happens with new created projects using the wizard tool.

King regards.

Comment: I ckecked the project and there are not Ivy dependencies. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Check your *index.gsp* file and remove the line showing the Groovy version.

*org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion* has changed to
[GroovySystem.getVersion](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovySystem.html#getVersion%28%29) in newer Groovy builds bundled in Grails.

Initially I would have said that you upgraded projects from previous Grails versions.

1. Install a new version of Grails
2. Update the application.properties file
3. Run grails upgrade
4. Create a new blank project and compare the BuildConfig.groovy to see if a dependency needs upgrading.

I think that the *index.gsp* modification will do it. If not, please add details about the actions that you're taking and when the error occurs(stacktrace will also be needed).

Comment: Hi rimero, Following you said, I figured out the issue happens with both, new projects and upgrated projects, but it is solved if you debug the application throught debug cofigurations option. It's really strange, is it?. Then, updating the index.gsp as you said, project works fine.  Thank you very much for your time. Best regards.